# MaterialUI DropDownMenu Multiple select using react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am facing issue with the multiselect dropdown, Can someone help me out.While configuring the API through Dropdown, Filter API need to be filter for the all 5 input multiselects based on the initial Dropdown After the filter should get the next avaliable data should be reflect  in the Next Dropdown selector.

```html
{
  "input_data": [],
  "filter_data": {
    "customers": [
      "Asda"
    ],
    "sub_categories": [
      "CAT CARE & TREATS"
    ],
    "brands": [
      "DREAMIES"
    ],
    "promo_groups": [
      "Dreamies 200g"
    ],
    "years": [
      "2021"
    ],
    "quarters": [
      "Q2"
    ]
  },
  "level": "feature_type"
}
```